# Laravel Multi tenant application - SSL certificate for not physical subdomain

Tags: laravel, ssl, subdomain, wildcard, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant application in Laravel at ex: [www.website.com](http://www.website.com). Each Tenant chooses his username and can access his section of the site on ex: tenant1.website.com

everything works correctly, my problem is SSL for the subdomains of the tenants (which being so many I don't want to physically create a subdomain on CPanel)

I am familiar with Wildcard SSL with which you can define unlimited number of subdomains and apply the same certificate, but in my case the subdomain is not physically specified, I am identifying it with wildcards only, all subdomains point to single domain/server only, it is the application that understands and behaves accordingly.

Can anyone guide me on this? I have searched everywhere for a possible solution without success.

I tried to install a Wildcard SSL on my hosting, following the guides I found, but it ended up that the hosting told me that in any case I had to create each of the subdomains manually and install the certificate...

Comment: I think this is a very wide question, and without some configuration/architecture specifications, anything could be setup for this system to run like it is actually doing so. You need to add way more info, but I think it narrows down to a webserver configuration and/or something that Laravel would have to understand (you have to change code maybe?). I would also ask this on [sf] because seems more a webserver issue than anything else, but still, you are lacking a lot of info, so it is impossible to help you